# Can I exchange test kovan eth to main eth?

Tags: ether, testing, kovan

I have some test eth. But I don't know how to use them. Can transfer as real eth Or what I have to do that please help me. Or I can sold them. In that case at how much cost can I sold.

Comment: No they have no value and only for testing and u can get them for free

Answer (score 0):

You can not sold testnet eth anywhere. This is has 0 value. You can use testnet eth on devlope smartcontract and testing purpose.